# kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Look at this very basic linux module:

```
static ssize_t checksec_write(struct file *f, const char __user *buf,size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
    unsigned long addr_fonction_userspace;

    memcpy(&addr_fonction_userspace,buf,sizeof(unsigned long));

    void (*functionPtr)(void);
    functionPtr = addr_fonction_userspace;
    (*functionPtr)();

    return len;
}
```

This module works this /dev/checksec char device.

and look at this basic c userland program:

```
void fonction_userland();

void fonction_userland()
{
    asm ("nop");
}

void main()
{
    FILE *f=fopen("/dev/checksec","w");
    unsigned long addr_fonction_userland = &fonction_userland;
    fwrite(&addr_fonction_userland,sizeof(unsigned long),1,f);
}
```

When i run the program, i get this error in dmesg:

```
kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt?
```

I understand it is an exploit attempt, because this is what i am trying to learn. But i do not understand why the page is NX-protected. The function is not in a non execute page, it is a userland function.
SMEP and SMAP are not enabled (bits 0 in CR4 regsiter)

Thanks a lot

Comment: If `fread()` buffers data, the system call (and therefore your driver) will get the address of that buffer and not `&fonction_userland`. You may try to either disable this buffering (see e.g. `set[v]buf()`) or use `open()` + `read()`.

Comment: See my edit. I should not work with a copy of buffer this way ?

Comment: Normally you shouldn't be changing the question other than to clarify it. And I don't understand what the edited code is supposed to do better than the original one. Anyhow, what I was trying to say is that `fopen()` and `fread()` are implemented on top of `open()` and `read()` and that `fread()`, to speed things up, may use a buffer (not your buffer, one of its own) into which it would get more bytes from `read()` than you're requesting. And if that's what's happening, your driver will get the address of that buffer and the buffer memory would likely be non-executable.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze The function `fonction_userland` itself is not copied anywhere, only its address is copied to the `addr_fonction_userspace` local variable in the kernel module. So whether `fread` does any buffering is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bob5421 See what happens if you call `fonction_userland` in user mode before `fwrite`. Check for errors returned from `fwrite`, `fopen`, and `memcpy`. Print the address of `fonction_userland` in user mode and in the kernel module.

Comment: @HadiBrais The initial version of the question had `&fonction_userland` passed to `fread()` with the expectation that the kernel would see this address and attempt to execute the function at this address. But if `fread()` uses its own buffer, the kernel sees the address of the buffer instead of `&fonction_userland`.